# neo4j matching two different relationships and retrieving count while avoiding cartesian product

Tags: neo4j, cartesian-product

So I have database in which I want to retrieve the result that has the relationship "Reviewed" and in this result I want to retrieve entities with relationship "acted_in" and return the movie with highest number of cast members.

This is the code I wrote:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[r2:REVIEWED]->(movie:Movie)<-[r:ACTED_IN]-(actors:Person) 
RETURN movie.title as Movie_name, count(actors) as no_of_cast 
ORDER BY no_of_cast DESC
Limit 1
```

It returns the correct movie name but the number of cast members is a cartesian product of the persons who reviewed and the persons who acted in.

The result I get after the collect function on actors is

```
"The Replacements"  ["Brooke Langton", "Keanu Reeves", "Orlando Jones", "Gene Hackman", "Brooke Langton", "Keanu Reeves", "Orlando Jones", "Gene Hackman", "Brooke Langton", "Keanu Reeves", "Orlando Jones", "Gene Hackman"]
```

It repeats the actors the number of times relationship "reviewed" is present in that movie node.

How can I avoid this and get the correct number of cast members which is 4. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe a small schema of your db entities & relations would help ?

Comment: @Antonin; it is the movie database so it is an example database when you install neo4j desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get multiple/duplicate actors is because the same movie is being reviewed by more than one person (reviewers).  To remove duplicates, you can use the keyword "DISTINCT".

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[r2:REVIEWED]->(movie:Movie)<-[r:ACTED_IN]-(actors:Person) 
RETURN movie.title as Movie_name, count(distinct actors) as no_of_cast 
ORDER BY no_of_cast DESC
```

Result:

```
╒═══════════════════╤════════════╕
│"Movie_name"       │"no_of_cast"│
╞═══════════════════╪════════════╡
│"The Replacements" │4           │
├───────────────────┼────────────┤
│"Cloud Atlas"      │4           │
├───────────────────┼────────────┤
│"The Da Vinci Code"│4           │
├───────────────────┼────────────┤
│"The Birdcage"     │3           │
├───────────────────┼────────────┤
│"Unforgiven"       │3           │
└───────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some other options for improvement.

You don't really want paths that include the reviewer, that's what causing a cross product (reviewer rows x actor rows). Instead, this is a condition, that the only movies you are interested in are those where someone has reviewed it. You can move that part of the pattern to the WHERE clause instead:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)
WHERE ()-[:REVIEWED]->(movie)
WITH movie, size((movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-()) as no_of_cast 
ORDER BY no_of_cast DESC
LIMIT 1
RETURN movie.title as Movie_name, no_of_cast
```

Note also that instead of doing an aggregation, we're getting the degree of the :ACTED_IN relationship on the node for the number of cast using size(). This is more efficient, since we don't need to perform any expansions or aggregations to get this value.

Also we're waiting until after we've gotten our single top result to project that title property. Property access can be expensive, so it's best to defer it until you have your minimal result set.

Comment: it does not give the correct output. It returns a product again in which it gives the no_of_cast as 172.

Comment: You're right that it didn't give correct output, but it wasn't because of any cross product. I forgot to add the `movie` reference in the size pattern, so it was returning the total count of :ACTED_IN relationships in the entire graph rather than for that specific node on that row. Here's the fix: `size((movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-())`, note how `(movie)` here constraints the pattern so we're only looking for the degree of incoming :ACTED_IN relationships for the specific node.